# Does kafka error handling works for SMT errors in kafka connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to use multiple SMT for kafka connector but if there is an error in SMT the kafka error handling is not working. Can someone please confirm that error handling and dlq works for SMT errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`errors.tolernance` only applies for the Connect task exceptions, not for transforms.